# [UIView hash]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6eef8a0 error

Tags: iphone, ipad

i am trying to  jump to one viewControllers view from another viewControllers view and during this phase im getting a crash on the device. I have my NSZombieEnabled and it is giving a error message as **[UIView hash]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6eef8a0**

Can anyone throw some light on this please..... Thankyou

Comment: well... there must be an error somewhere in your code... but if you don't post it how can someone here try to solve it? All we can get by nw is that you are calling a method to some object which doesn't exist at the moment, you may have deallocated it before you try to call it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you tell , when this exception occurs? I mean when it "jump"  (push or present) the controller from A to B, or when it return back from controller B to A.?

Comment: Hi hari... actually iim not using a navigation view controller here.. im just adding  a view as subview to another view.... for the first two times im getting it absolutely fine, but it is getting crashed exactly the third time... and it's happening only device(not on simulator....) any clues???

Comment: try to use the breakpoints in dealloc method. You might be releasing an object, which is already released. It is really hard to find error without looking at your code